# Google Drive API v2: Transfer file ownership to admin user

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible for a super admin to take ownership of a file that is currently owned by an arbitrary user? If so, which end point can do this? I've spent time digging through the API documentation and I'm not coming up with a clear answer. Everything I've found is related to the 1st version of the API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible.

1. look at how to use oauth2 for "delegation of authority". https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
2. read the drive api docs on how to use delegation on their api.
3. look at the drive api that changes ownership. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update

the key part is calling that api using the service account that is impersonating that user.

beware of rate quotas using this method. if you have many files to change, you need to take care the rate is not too fast (say one per second).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the current owner can transfer ownership of a file to another user. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update

> transferOwnership boolean Whether changing a role to 'owner'
>   downgrades the current owners to writers. Does nothing if the
>   specified role is not 'owner'. (Default: false)

Comment: this does not answer the question. hes asking if an admin can do it, not the user.

Comment: an admin cannot do it, he needs to impersonate the user.

Comment: yes he can which my answers says. and yes by impersonating which is the key part here.